# Factory for a View in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, factory

There is an user control for `ContextMenu` which will be re-used in other user controls. The problem is the controls which would like to use this `Contextmenu` needs to create the `ContextMenuViewModel` and populate its `DataContext` which is the normal practice.

Is there a way to create a factory for the View so it will be created on the fly and not worried about its data context from the control which is consuming it?

Comment: I see you're in the mvvm world, does that include prism?  It gets real simple with prism, but is also doable with straight mvvm.

Comment: :) no it doesn't include prism.

Comment: Where do you want the context menu's data context to come from?

Comment: Context menu's data will be provided by the user control that uses this context menu

Comment: Would it be solved by using the control as a template?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Locator pattern

Ex:

uses of a “Locator” such as:

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

There is locators created in the application.

```
<Application x:Class="XXX.App"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:XXX.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
...
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"  />   
...     
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The class "Locator":

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{            
   private static MainViewModel _main;    

   /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.

   public ViewModelLocator()            
   {                
      _main = new MainViewModel();            
   }    

  /// Gets the Main property which defines the main viewmodel.            

  public MainViewModel Main
  {                
     get                
       {              
       return _main;                
       }            
  }        


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer let me verify this and get back to you :)

Comment: "ViewModel-Locator" is considered an anti-pattern because the lifetime of a ViewModel should match the View, not the length of the container - and because this approach doesn't support N-ary views (e.g. an MDI). Instead, a better example is demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017579/wpf-mvvm-ioc-alternative-to-service-locator-pattern-need-dependency-in-view-c/50024624