# WPF, MVVM IoC: Alternative to Service Locator Pattern. Need dependency in View code behind

Tags: wpf, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

Following several guides I have a application layout like below using WPF .NET 4.7.1 and MVVM-Light. I'm totally new to WPF btw.

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="My.App" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:My.ViewModel" 
         StartupUri="View\MainView.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewmodel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

That registers the "ViewModelLocator" class as a resources and sets the WPF startup to "View/MainView.xaml".

MainView.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="My.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding  Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Where the ViewModelLocator is used like a Service Locator Pattern. Here setting the DataContext to my "MainViewModel" (not shown). As much as I do not like this, I can live with it in the WPF XAML context. However now it turns out that I need a dependency in the code-behind of the view (not the ViewModel).

MainView.cs:

```
public partial class MainView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainView()
   {
       // Need to access dependency here.          
   }
}
```

Now I could just call the ViewModelLocator directly in that constructor and have that resolve from my IoC container - but then I've completely given in and accepting that pattern.

I would prefer to have the dependency injected in the ctor of course, and if that is possible, I would also leave the ViewModelLocator entirely and inject the ViewModel here.

So question is, are there some standard way of instructing WPF application to use my container? And if yes, is it adviceable to go down that path and not use the ViewModelLocator thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely do not have to use the `ViewModelLocator` (Side note, the service locator pattern has had it's fair share of criticism lately as an anti-pattern, but I'll let you form your own opinion). MVVM Light and other Libraries basically give you access to a tool kit. You don't need to use all of the tools, and you should only use what is necessary for your specific domain.

Outside of the `ViewModelLocator`, there are two patterns known as `ViewModel First` and `View First` both have their pro's and cons.  However both provide a means to decouple your code, which means it's not difficult to switch later.

As for constructing an application using MVVM Light without the service locator, my implementation of the View First method looks something like this.

I've heard the opinion that `ViewModel First` is preferred, however I find View First to be more simplistic for Test Driven Development (TDD)

App.xaml.cs (Application Code Behind)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
        //Container Builder
        var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
        var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

BootStrapper.cs (I'm using AutoFac in this case, but you can easily substitute.)

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    public IContainer BootStrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>().AsSelf();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
//I rolled my own ViewModelBase, but you can use MVVM Light's ViewModelBase
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string DisplayProgram
    {
        get { return _displayProgram; }
        //MVVM Light's ViewModelBase uses RaisePropertyChanged();
        set { _displayProgram = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        //Called from view code behind.
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs (MainWindow Code Behind)

```
//When MainWindow.Show()..
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
    //Container resolves dependencies
    public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //Let base Window class do its thing.
        InitializeComponent();

        //Handle loaded event
        Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;

        //Hold on to the MainWindowViewModel, and set it as the windows DataContext            
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, vrey helpful and a much cleaner approach imo. But suppose I have this in MainView.xaml: "<views:SubView/>". WPF will expect a default parameterless constructor. Would I bind to a property in MainView.cs and have my ISubView injected in the MainView ctor? And I guess this way, my designer would not work. I was hoping that WPF supported containers like through CommonServiceLocator or similar.

Comment: as usual, "It depends..."  How complex is your application? How many sub views? Are these sub views going to need to communicate? If you just want to make it work for now (and keep the designer working to edit your window) it's reasonable to make the ugly decision to make the CTOR parameterless and new up a ViewModel, refactoring can always be done later when things become clearer.

Comment: It really is a pain to break the designer and then find out your users don't like the placement of a button lol.

Comment: I see, so - in general - would it be adviceable not to start using dependency injection in views? The application will grow quite large over time. And I'm looking for best practices here. We're starting to use WPF for the first time and don't have the experience to break out of common WPF usage just because we're used to use DI all over the place..

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I added the conditional "If you just want to make it work for now." because I don't know the size and scope of your app. I left that decision to you. You absolutely should use DI for the Views, but for a far-fetched example, if you "get it to work right now" you may find you don't want `SubViews` in your `MainView`. and instead you want more of a composite application. Or you may find MVVM-Light is too 'Light' and switch to Prism Library.